# Can't invoke new operator for list initialization with a std::initializer_list?

Tags: c++, c++11

So, with C++11, we got a new form of operator new:

```
auto dynamicArray = new int[5]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

The so called "list-initialized" format.

My question is whether or not it's possible to call this form of the new operator using a `std::initializer_list`, as in:

```
std::initializer_list<int> initializer = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
auto dynamicArray = new int[5] initializer; //Doesn't work
```

Wrapping `initializer` in braces also doesn't work (conversion from `std::initializer_list<int>` to `int`). Adding parenthesis also does not seem to help.

I am aware that it is possible to use variadic templates to create a similar effect (and avoid using `std::initializer_list` altogether), but would prefer to avoid this solution as the forwarding references create some fun when it comes to overload resolution on the function I'm using this in.

I am also aware that I can use `std::malloc` and `std::free` to get uninitialized memory and do the filling myself with `std::uninitialized_copy`.

Comment: Not possible outside the solutions you referenced. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Fair enough. I ended up going with the `std::uninitialized_copy` approach. Was really just hoping I was missing some sort of syntactic shortcut. It appears that that was not the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible. `new` follows the rules of direct  initialization. It's ill-formed to direct initialize an array with parentheses. You can only direct initialize arrays using braces. And what follows is list initialization. Since it's an aggregate, it then performs aggregate initialization, and there's nothing in aggregate initialization that allows you to copy the elements of an `std::initializer_list` like that.

`auto a = new int[5]();` is valid because the rules state that `()` performs value initialization, *otherwise* it is ill-formed.

Answer (score 2):

As stated elsewhere, it is not possible.

You already stated possible workarounds. Here are a couple of others:

#### Use `vector`

If you use `vector` instead of rolling your own dynamic array, it will take the initializer list for you.

```
    std::initializer_list<int> initializer = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    std::vector<int> dynamicArray(initializer);
```

#### Helper template function

You don't need variadic templates. Just one that accepts the initializer list and returns your dynamically allocated array:

```
template <typename T> T *
make_dynamic_array (std::initializer_list<T> l) {
    auto da = new T[l.size()];
    std::copy(l.begin(), l.end(), da);
    return da;
}
```

Comment: Props on suggesting vector, but it won't actually work for my case. I am implementing a special container class of my own. The issue with your second alternative is that it comes at an increased performance cost compared to either of the two I originally mentioned. Namely, you default initialize everything, then reinitialize everything. Perhaps a smart compiler can do the dead-code elimination, but I don't want to count on it.

Comment: The default initialization overhead is only an issue of the type of the array element is non-POD.

Comment: Fair. My use case is templated for use over all types.

Comment: I also do not understand why you feel a `vector` would not work, as many container classes implement themselves as wrappers around other containers.

Comment: Indeed they do. It actually *would* probably work, but at the cost of an extra indirection for all actions. My container has unusual lifetime properties.

Comment: I would have recommended `std::array` rather than `std::vector`, except that `std::array` does not accept `initializer_list` in its constructor.

Comment: Also not a bad suggestion, though it does perform default-initialization. Aggregate initialization should also not be forgotten.